# Java - How to print dictionary value

Tags: java, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary where it looks like <String, String[]>.
However whenever it is not allowing me to get the elements of the array. Am I doing it wrongly?

```
Dictionary zones = new Hashtable();
String[] countries = {"country1", "country2"};
zones.put("Red", countries);
System.out.println(zones.get("Red")[0]);
```

I am guessing that I can't use array for dictionary value? Is there an alternative to this?

Comment: What is Dictionary class?

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan Hashtable extends Dictionary class. `The  Dictionary class is the abstract parent of any
  class, such as Hashtable, which maps keys to values.`

Comment: Ahhh so its like a `Map` hmm I didn't know that. Thanks

Comment: `Dictionary` and `Hashtable` are both legacy. You’ll find better alternatives included with Java. Read their Javadoc for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use generics or use type cast.
This is using generics:

```
Dictionary<String, String[]> zones = new Hashtable<>();
String[] countries = {"country1", "country2"};
zones.put("Red", countries);
System.out.println(zones.get("Red")[0]);
```

This is using type cast:

```
Dictionary zones = new Hashtable();
String[] countries = {"country1", "country2"};
zones.put("Red", countries);
System.out.println(((String[])zones.get("Red"))[0]);
```

The `get` method on Dictionary returns `Object` so you have to cast it to `String[]`. If you use generics then compiler handles this for you and you don't have to write type casts.